# Binding TCP server to external SOCKS server

Tags: binding, tcp, ip, socks

As it is possible to use the SOCKS protocol to hide your IP while browsing the web, or to use other protocols such as FTP, I'm wondering whether it's possible to host a server instance on this IP, in order to hide the hosts IP.

I've been looking around and found the LINUX tool RedSocks (https://github.com/darkk/redsocks), but it isn't clear to me whether this makes it possible to bind to an external IP, and if it's possible to bind server instances to an external IP.

So my question is, could my goal be reached, and if yes, is it possible to reach this with RedSocks or am I completely wrong?

Comment: Better to ask this on serverfault

Answer (score 1):

> As it is possible to use the SOCKS protocol to hide your IP while browsing the web, or to use other protocols such as FTP, I'm wondering whether it's possible to host a server instance on this IP, in order to hide the hosts IP.

It isn't even necessary. The question doesn't make sense. The SOCKS protocol does the hiding. There's nothing special about the IP address that the proxy is running at, and running another server there won't hide it. Just use the proxy in front of your server.

> I've been looking around and found the LINUX tool RedSocks (https://github.com/darkk/redsocks), but it isn't clear to me whether this makes it possible to bind to an external IP

Nothing makes that possible, but SOCKS lets you present that IP address as your own. So does NAT.

> and if it's possible to bind server instances to an external IP.

Ditto.

> So my question is, could my goal be reached, and if yes, is it possible to reach this with RedSocks or am I completely wrong?

You're completely wrong. You're attributing magical properties to the IP address itself, where it is SOCKS that is doing the magic. Not that it's magical.